# How to change join and group by SQL to ORM in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I'm new in Django. So, I want to join two models which are `company` and `client` and count the number of clients for each of the company. Here the SQL

```
SELECT Company_company.name, count(Client_client.cid)
FROM Company_company
LEFT JOIN Client_client
ON Company_company.comid = Client_client.comid_id
GROUP BY Company_company.name;
```

But since in Django, we use ORM. So I'm a little bit confusing since I'm a beginner. I already refer few SQL to ORM converter website such as [Django ORM](https://www.tech-programmer.com/2020/04/convert-sql-to-django-orm.html) and do some try and error. But, I didn't know where the problem since I want the output from the ORM to be classified into a different array. Here is my code:

```
labels = []
data = []

queryClientCompany = client.objects.values('comid').annotate(c=Count('cid')).values('comid__name','c')

for comp in queryClientCompany:
    labels.append(comp.comid__name)
    data.append(comp.c)
```

Here some of the relevant things in the `client` and `company` models:

```
class client (models.Model):
    
    #client info
    cid = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    comid = models.ForeignKey(company,related_name='companys',
            on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING,verbose_name="Company",null = True, blank = True)


class company(models.Model):

    comid = models.AutoField(_('Company'),primary_key = True)

    #company info
    name = models.CharField(_('Company Name'),max_length = 50)
```

The error stated that the `comid__name` is not defined. So actually how to append the result? I hope someone can help me. Thank you for helping in advanced.

Comment: Please share the given models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should query from the opposite side to perform the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` between `company` and `client` (and not `client` and `company`):

```
from django.db.models import Count

labels = []
data = []

queryClientCompany = company.objects.annotate(
    c=Count('companys__cid')
)

for comp in queryClientCompany:
    labels.append(comp.name)
    data.append(comp.c)
```

The `companys` part is due to the `related_name='copanys'`, but it does not make much sense to name this relation that way. The [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) specifies how to access the `Client`s for a given `Company`, so `clients` is a more appropriate value for the `related_name`:

```
class client (models.Model):
    cid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    comid = models.ForeignKey(
        company,
        related_name='clients',
        on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING,
        verbose_name="Company",
        null = True,
        blank = True
    )
```

then the query is:

```
from django.db.models import Count

labels = []
data = []

queryClientCompany = company.objects.annotate(
    c=Count('clients__cid')
)

for comp in queryClientCompany:
    labels.append(comp.name)
    data.append(comp.c)
```

Comment: I have tried your solution. But it didn't working. It stated that there is no client__id in company. I think that is because comid is FK in client models, and it is 1:M relationship

Comment: @jat: it is not `__id`, but `__cid`. The fact that it is a 1:m relation is exactly why this should be done that way. Django can follow relations in reverse, and thus adds a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` itself. Can you please edit your question and share the relevant models.

Comment: Sorry I mistype. I use __cid but not working as well. I already edit my question and share the relevant models.

Comment: @jat: then it is `companys__cid`, but it does not make much sense to specify `related_name='companys'`, since this is the relation in *reverse*, so from `Comapny` to `Client`.

Comment: I think i already understand what the related_name mean. And your solution work!! Thank you. But, I have one question, why we need to put double underscore before the cid (__cid)?

Comment: @jat: to look "through" the relation. Although since `cid` is not `NULL`-able, we can use `Count('companys')` (or `Count('clients')` if you rename the relation).

Comment: I think I understand more now. Thank you for your explanation and helps.